# Match similar not same column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I have two tables.
Table A  as under:

```
ID    |   Val1   |   Val2   | Val 3
1       55.198        200     67.501
1        68.647       205      149.011
1         150.545     210       250.124
```

and  Table B as under:

```
ID_From_TableA    |   Val1   |   Val2
  1                    55.199    200   
  1                    56.156    200
  1                    68.647    205
```

Table A has unique value if we combine

> ID and Val2

and

I want to update column **Val2**  of tableB with **Val2** of TableA when, **TableA.ID = Table2.ID_From_TableA** and **TableA.Val1 is approximately equal to TableB.Val1**

I tried below given code but it didn't work

```
select B.ID, B.Val1 
B.Val2 = A.VAL1
from TableA A
left join TableB B
on A.ID_From_TableA = B.ID
where (B.VAL1-A.Val1)>1
```

also I tried, but didnt work

```
 select B.ID, B.Val1 
    B.Val2 = A.VAL1
    from TableA A
    left join TableB B
    on A.ID_From_TableA = B.ID
    where B.VAL1 like A.Val1
```

Can someone please help?

PS - I am using MSSQL

Comment: define `approximately equal`

Comment: like the example given in my question - 55.198 and  55.199. Mainly less than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an update join, and make sure that `TableB` appears on the left side of that join:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Val2 = a.Val2
FROM tableB b
INNER JOIN tableA a
    ON b.ID = a.ID AND ABS(b.Val1 - a.Val1) < 0.01;
```

This assumes a tolerance of less than 0.01 difference between `Val1` values as implying equality.  You may tune this tolerance to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but it give me error - Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: What database are you using?  I assumed MySQL.

Comment: Sorry I should have put that in my question. I am using MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tim,

I tried below code and it worked like a charm..

```
update 
    TableB
set
    Val2 = a.Val2
from TableB b
inner join TableA a
on a.ID = bookmarking.ID and ABS(bookmarking.Val1) between a.Val2 and a.Val2
```

Comment: This query has nothing to do with your original question.  I have no idea why you posted this.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the Val3 in the question.